# Find all holomorphic functions giving $ u(x,y) = \phi (x^2+y^2) $

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find all holomorphic function , $ f= u+iv $, if

$$u(x, y)=\phi(x^2+y^2)$$

As far as I know, for a function two be holomorphic, it has to be harmonic, so
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

That gives us

$$(x^2+y^2)\phi''(x^2+y^2) +\phi'(x^2+y^2)= 0$$

Can I use the notation $x^2+y^2=t$ so that
$$t\phi''(t)+\phi'(t)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{\phi''(t)}{\phi'(t)}=-\frac{1}{t} 
\Rightarrow  \log(\phi'(t))=-\log(t)\Rightarrow \\ 
\log(t\phi'(t))=0 \Rightarrow t\phi'(t) = 1 \Rightarrow \phi(t)=log(t) ?$$

Moving further on , 
$$dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}dy$$

Using Cauchy-Riemann:

$$dv = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy$$

$$dv = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}dy-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}dx$$

So, 
$$v = 2 \arctan(\frac{x}{y})-2 \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$
and 
$$ f(x, y) = \log(x^2+y^2) + 2 \arctan(\frac{x}{y})-2 \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$ 
Is this correct?

Comment: What conditions have the derivatives of a function to fulfil that it is holomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your function is supposed to be entire, i.e. holomorphic on all of $\mathbb C$.

Let $a = \text{Re}(f(1))$.  Thus $g(z) = i (f(z) - a)$ is real on the circle $|z| = 1$.  Note that $h(z) = \overline{g(1/\overline{z})}$ is analytic on 
$\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$ and equal to $g(z)$ on $|z|=1$, so it is equal to $g(z)$ everywhere.  In particular, $g$ is bounded.  Now use Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is correct. Setting $x^2+y^2=t$ you found
$$
0=t \,\phi''(t)+\phi'(t)=(t \, \phi'(t))'
$$
so $t \,\phi'(t)$ is constant. Which $\phi'$ and $\phi$ satisfy this equation? Then check if for each one $\phi(|z|^2)$ is the real part of a holomorphic function (in some domain).